# How to add jquery form validation in dynamic generated html?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-validation-engine

I have created a dynamic html block. When you click on add more button generate three field name, from-date, to-date and i apple the validation on this field but it's not working.

[image]
Dynamic post fields name :

```
<input type="text" name="data[User][title][]" />
<input type="text" name="data[User][fromdate][]" />
<input type="text" name="data[User][todate][]" />
```

Above fields are dynamic generated html and i want to give a validation every new generated field from Jquery Validation but it's not working.

Jquery Validation Rules :

```
 $(".UserForm").validate({
ignore: "", 
errorElement: 'label',
errorClass: 'error', 
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).parents("div.form-group").addClass("get-error");
},
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
  $(element).parents("div.form-group").removeClass("get-error");
},

    rules: {
        "data[User][title][]": {
            required : true, 
        },
        "data[User][fromdate][]": {
            required : true
        },
         "data[User][todate][]": {
            required : true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "data[User][title][]": {
            required: "Please enter title", 
        },
        "data[User][fromdate][]": {
            required: "Please select fromdate", 
        },
        "data[User][todate][]": {
            required: "Please select todate",
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: Any one have answer this question

Comment: You need to be more specific than "not working". That's very vague. Provide details about what you expect to happen, what actually happens, any error messages generated (e.g. in the JS console), that sort of thing.

Comment: @Greg Schmidt Hello i will post a screen short. what actual i want.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561712/jquery-validate-plugin-on-dynamic-form-inputs-not-working

Comment: @tarikul05 Its work only one fields